# Unable to start the hive container according to the commands in hive quickstart

Tags: docker, hive

I follow the **QuickStart** section of [hive quickstart](https://hive.apache.org/developement/quickstart/) to start hiveserver2 in docker container. However, I can't start hiveserver2 container successfully. This failed container outputs the following content,

```
+ : derby
+ SKIP_SCHEMA_INIT=false
+ export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/opt/hive/conf
+ HIVE_CONF_DIR=/opt/hive/conf
+ '[' -d '' ']'
+ export 'HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS= -Xmx1G '
+ HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=' -Xmx1G '
+ [[ false == \f\a\l\s\e ]]
+ initialize_hive
+ /opt/hive/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initOrUpgradeSchema
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
HiveSchemaTool:Parsing failed.  Reason: Missing required option: [-help print this message, -alterCatalog Alter a catalog, requires --catalogLocation and/or --catalogDescription parameter as well, -initSchemaTo Schema initialization to a version, -upgradeSchemaFrom Schema upgrade from a version, -moveDatabase Move a database between catalogs.  Argument is the database name. Requires --fromCatalog and --toCatalog parameters as well, -moveTable Move a table to a different database.  Argument is the table name. Requires --fromCatalog, --toCatalog, --fromDatabase, and --toDatabase  parameters as well., -initSchema Schema initialization, -createCatalog Create a catalog, requires --catalogLocation parameter as well, -upgradeSchema Schema upgrade, -info Show config and schema details, -validate Validate the database]
usage: schemaTool
 -alterCatalog <arg>                Alter a catalog, requires
                                    --catalogLocation and/or
                                    --catalogDescription parameter as well
 -catalogDescription <arg>          Description of new catalog
 -catalogLocation <arg>             Location of new catalog, required when
                                    adding a catalog
 -createCatalog <arg>               Create a catalog, requires
                                    --catalogLocation parameter as well
 -dbOpts <databaseOpts>             Backend DB specific options
 -dbType <databaseType>             Metastore database type
 -driver <driver>                   driver name for connection
 -dryRun                            list SQL scripts (no execute)
 -fromCatalog <arg>                 Catalog a moving database or table is
                                    coming from.  This is required if you
                                    are moving a database or table.
 -fromDatabase <arg>                Database a moving table is coming
                                    from.  This is required if you are
                                    moving a table.
 -help                              print this message
 -ifNotExists                       If passed then it is not an error to
                                    create an existing catalog
 -info                              Show config and schema details
 -initSchema                        Schema initialization
 -initSchemaTo <initTo>             Schema initialization to a version
 -metaDbType <metaDatabaseType>     Used only if upgrading the system
                                    catalog for hive
 -moveDatabase <arg>                Move a database between catalogs.
                                    Argument is the database name.
                                    Requires --fromCatalog and --toCatalog
                                    parameters as well
 -moveTable <arg>                   Move a table to a different database.
                                    Argument is the table name. Requires
                                    --fromCatalog, --toCatalog,
                                    --fromDatabase, and --toDatabase
                                    parameters as well.
 -passWord <password>               Override config file password
 -servers <serverList>              a comma-separated list of servers used
                                    in location validation in the format
                                    of scheme://authority (e.g.
                                    hdfs://localhost:8000)
 -toCatalog <arg>                   Catalog a moving database or table is
                                    going to.  This is required if you are
                                    moving a database or table.
 -toDatabase <arg>                  Database a moving table is going to.
                                    This is required if you are moving a
                                    table.
 -upgradeSchema                     Schema upgrade
 -upgradeSchemaFrom <upgradeFrom>   Schema upgrade from a version
 -url <url>                         connection url to the database
 -userName <user>                   Override config file user name
 -validate                          Validate the database
 -verbose                           only print SQL statements
Schema initialization failed!
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'Schema initialization failed!'
+ exit 1
```

The version of docker is `Docker version 24.0.5, build ced0996`. The OS is `Linux version 5.15.0-82-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-046) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #91~20.04.1-Ubuntu`.

Could anyone tell me if it's a problem with the hive image or the installation steps?